# Capital letters URL with cPanel?

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, cpanel

my website have this link, but when I change hello to HELLO, page is not found

```
www.mywebsite.com/hello
```

I've searched a lot of question about capital letters URL. The answer is basically the same, which is setting the .htaccess and setting the RewriteMap httpd.conf. My website is using cPanel 62.0.15 and I don't think that I can access httpd.conf. I didn't found that file anywhere.
Is there any other way to get capital letters URL working? Or where can I find the httpd.conf file in cPanel?

My .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?xparam=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Just call `$xparam = strtolower($_GET['xparam'])` in your application code.

Answer (score 0):

If you add NC as a RewriteRule then this makes the match case insensitive:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?xparam=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Becomes ..

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?xparam=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html for more